# Illegal operation in Greasemonkey script compiler

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script and I'm using a [Greasemonkey to xpi compiler](https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php)

I use this script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Teste Script
// @author         Bla
// ==/UserScript==

var Main = setInterval(
    function () {
        alert(window.location.href);
    }, 1000);
```

and when I install the xpi, I keep getting this error:

> Error: Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

Already tried `window.alert` and it still shows the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It looks like the converter is somehow broken.

If i take an hello world script with this content:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Webmonkey's Hello World
// @namespace     http://www.webmonkey.com
// @description   A basic example of Greasemonkey that causes an alert at each page load.
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==


alert('Monkey sez... "Hello World!"');
```

The error is still there. So i don't suspect that your code is the problem, more the compiler.

I've never created an XPI by myself, but i think that you should try it by hand and see if that works. Perhaps will this problem be fixed in the future ( watch his [github](https://github.com/arantius/greasemonkey-compiler) page for updates )